# Duplicate Rows Loading Data From MySQL to DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I'm experiencing duplication of rows using MySQL and VB.NET

Here's my code:

```
db_con.Open()
Dim db_da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select U_ID,U_FNAME,U_MNAME,U_LNAME,U_YEAR,U_SECT,U_VALIDATION from TBL_USER where U_SECT = '" & SRAMngt_Mod.cmb_sect.SelectedItem & "'", db_con)
Dim db_dt As New DataTable
db_da.Fill(db_dt)
db_con.Close()
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.DataSource = db_dt
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "U_ID"
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "U_FNAME"
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "U_MNAME"
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "U_LNAME"
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "U_YEAR"
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "U_SECT"
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "U_VALIDATION"
```

Is there something wrong with my structure or code?

Comment: Please stop shouting. Explain *exactly* what you're seeing ("duplication of rows" doesn't give enough detail), format your post, and generally make sure it looks how *you'd* want it to look if you were considering answering.

Comment: sorry bout my question im newbie here :/ hmm

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints - but be aware that writing in ALLCAPS is like shouting pretty much anywhere on the net...

Comment: Are you sure there aren't actually duplicates in the database?  Are you seeing duplicates in the PK or any unique fields?

Comment: I dont have data bindings so I created those _UNBOUND_ columns, with header text , so id tried that code above, ..... the code worked, the data on my database loaded to the columns id created. but after that it repeat/duplicates another columns with the `DataPropertyName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reformat your query such as

```
SELECT U_ID AS [User ID], U_FNAME AS [First Name] etc...
```

Then you don't need to set the columns in the DataGridView just set

```
SRAMngt_Mod.DataGridView1.DataSource = db_dt
```

And DataGridView will display the data as it comes from database and set the column header to the names you specified in your query as the display name.

If you still experiencing rows duplicate try clearing the DataTable before you fill command.

```
db_dt.Clear()
```

if problem remains then run the query on your database and see the result. If it returns duplicate rows then the criteria you set in the query is not unique choose another unique value.

Hope this helps.